# SQL query for two possible values?

Tags: t-sql, flags, sql-server-2008

I am using SSMS 2008 R2 and am trying to figure out the SQL select statement to select all records where two or more of the values are found.

These are the four possible values I am looking for.  If two or more of these values (SubstanceAbuse, BehaviorEmotion, SexualAbuse, DomesticViolence) are met, I want to set a new field to 1.  How do I do this?

```
    case when qav.[test_setup_details_caption] in ('Substance Abuse / Drug Use','Caregiver monitor youth for drug  alcohol use') then 1 else 0 end SubstanceAbuse,
    case when qav.[test_setup_details_caption] in ('Physical Aggression','Firesetting','Gang Involvement','Runaway Behavior') then 1 else 0 end BehaviorEmotion,
    case when qav.[test_setup_details_caption] = 'Problem Sexual Behavior' then 1 else 0 end SexualAbuse,
    case when qav.[test_setup_details_caption] LIKE '%Domestic%' then 1 else 0 end DomesticViolence,
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My suggestion would be to take the above statement and make it a virtual table in a new SELECT statement.  Then you can do a SUM on the ones (since they are calculated already) in your WHERE statement and display only

```
where (Sub + Beh + Sex + Dom) > 1
```

It would look something like this (pseudo-code):

```
SELECT t.*
FROM (SELECT sub case, Beh case, etc.
      FROM yourtable) t
WHERE (t.sub + t.Beh + t.Sex + t.Dom) > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like all you need is this WHERE clause:

```
WHERE SubstanceAbuse + BehaviorEmotion + SexualAbuse + DomesticViolence > 1
```

Comment: In essence you are correct David.  The only problem is that the WHERE clause gets calculated before the SELECT statement so if these case statements are in the SELECT, you cannot access them by their alias because the alias has not yet been created.  That is why in my answer I put the whole query inside the FROM statement so I could do something similar to what you were thinking.

Answer (score 0):

```
update myTable set myField = 1 where 2 <= (select SubstanceAbuse + BehaviorEmotion + SexualAbuse + DomesticViolence from ...)
```

Of course, this is just a template for your query, but you get the idea. If the answer is still unclear then I kindly ask you to give me more details.

Best regards,
Lajos Arpad.